# SQL same database relation

Tags: sql, relational-database

trying to figure something out - only starting learning SQL and I am puzzled by a challenge: I have a table that has 3 columns:

1. customer ID
2. account number
3. City

Each customer can have multiple accounts and each account can have multiple ID'S.
The city is per ID not account (city of residents).
I want to write a query that retrieves all accounts where ALL account owners are from a certain city (for example - City A). meaning that if a certain account has an owner in city A and an Owner in city B it will not be retrieved.
how would I do that??
see the example:

0. ACCOUNT     ID       CITY
1. 65489       1234     London
2. 12345       1567     New York
3. 12345       8956     New York
4. 11236       6324     Paris
5. 66523       1234     New York
6. 66523       3321     Paris
7. 11236       6639     New York

I am looking for an account that all owners live in NY so:
the only account here is 12345.
account 66523 is not viable - since it has an owner in Paris.

Comment: You don’t appear to have attached the example. In any case, please don’t attach/link to anything - edit your question to show sample data and then result you want to achieve based on that data

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood you correctly. Assuming your data is in the table *data* your query could be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    selected.account
FROM
    data AS selected
WHERE
    selected.city = 'New York'
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            data AS other
        WHERE
            other.account = selected.account
            AND other.city <> selected.city
    )
```